# Is there a transaction management for DAO in Spring framework?

Tags: spring, transactions, dao

Is there any kind of out-of-the-box transaction management support for pure DAO in Spring framework?

Comment: I'm curious... what is "pure DAO"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Spring has transaction management (see [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)).